# how make this page center on IE 9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9, centering

i have a little problem [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yj7mu/), this page at firefox, opera, chrome, has already center, but at IE 9 this page still at left.. tq for help....

Comment: It's centered for me in ie9...

Comment: THis has nothing to do with your centering but don't use `<font>` tags ... ever. instead replace with `<span style="color: #CC3300"> Our promise to you</span>`

Comment: @James Even better, use `<span class = "ColorText">` and define `ColorText` in CSS.

Comment: @maxpm yes you are right. I was just trying to show a direct conversion. But +1 you're definatley right and it would be the way I do it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First you need to change your width to something less than `100%`

Then you need to change

```
margin-top: 50px;
margin-left: 0 auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

to

```
margin: 50px auto 0;
```

and it should work.

**EDIT**

I should have taken a closer look!

I would also change your `.container`.  Give `width:auto;` a fixed width, `900px` for example.

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/yj7mu/3/

Comment: Great @Samuel. You're welcome. If this is the correct answer, you should click the checkmark beside the answer (to mark it answered).